# User uploaded images: limit file size on front end or reduce on back-end?

Tags: web-applications

I was wondering what the standard/best practice is with regard to managing user-uploaded images.

Obviously there needs to be a way to limit file sizes, but what's the best and most common practice here -- limit the size of the image that can be uploaded by the user, or reduce the size once it's uploaded on the back-end?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

In short I would say *It depends* on:

1. how much space you have,
2. how much images you will operate
3. how many users you serve.

I would consider three things:

1. Uploading bigger files takes more time (bad user experience).
2. Storing big files takes more space.
3. Serving big files takes more time (bad user experience again).

So, at best, all three above should be optimsed:

1. Files should be compressed/scaled down before upload (on user machine).
2. Files should be stored at some default size.
3. Files should be served at requested size (so if thumb of image is requested thumb should be served).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do both. It depends what you are using the images for. It's a good idea to have a file size limit for user uploads, in case someone decides they'd like to upload a [half GB picture of the moon](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/news/116932598.html) or something.

For example, Photo Bucket has these limits:
Free Accounts: Up to 5 MB each or 2048 x 1536 resolution
Pro Accounts: Up to 4000 x 3000 resolution

Facebook used to resize photos to a max height of 604 pixels, which changed last year to 720 pixels. They also offer a "high-res" checkbox option which allows users to optionally provide a link to download the larger version of their photos.

If the photos are only being used for display in a certain area, and the original does not need to be preserved, then I'd resize them to a width/height appropriate for your web app. If you need thumbnails, I'd generate those during the upload process too.